# C# ASP.net - Specific Column in RDLC is Not Showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I created a stored procedure and set this as my dataset. but I don't know why this column in table/tablix won't show up in RDLC.

[image: Column Not showing].

Here's my Query:

```
SELECT C.Cargo_Name,
       C.Range,
       C.Days,
       C.NumOfContainers,
       P.Amount,
       P.Container,
       C.Days * C.NumOfContainers * P.Amount AS Pesos
FROM   Container C
       INNER JOIN Prices P
            ON  C.Code = P.Code
WHERE  C.Control_ID = '100003'
       AND C.Cargo_Name = 'DRY CARGO'
```

and giving me this

[image: Output]

Comment: Please disregard the ** in C.Days * C.NumOfContainers * P.Amount AS Pesos

Answer (score 0):

I've not used/unsure what RDLC is, however, I've experienced similar where the data type of your calculated column ends up as a byte[] which won't display.

Also unsure what SQL back end you are using.  Try the below (Microsoft SQL Server dialect) and let me know if that fixes it:

```
SELECT C.Cargo_Name,
       C.Range,
       C.Days,
       C.NumOfContainers,
       P.Amount,
       P.Container,
       CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,2),C.Days * C.NumOfContainers * P.Amount) AS Pesos
FROM   Container C
       INNER JOIN Prices P
            ON  C.Code = P.Code
WHERE  C.Control_ID = '100003'
       AND C.Cargo_Name = 'DRY CARGO'
```